# Using the same view returned form variable for two different templates

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a subscribe form view which displays to a subscribe page, and I also want to display that same form in the home page, I tried using `{% include 'accounts/subscribe.html' %}` and tried also `{% extends 'accounts/subscribe.html' %}`in the home page (a recommendation from a similar question but not the same). How can I please go about this ?

view that leads to the subscribe.html

```
def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subscribe_form = EmailListForm(request.POST)
        if subscribe_form.is_valid():
            subscribe_form = subscribe_form.save()

            return render(request, 'accounts/subscribe_done.html', {'name': subscribe_form.name})

    else:
        subscribe_form = EmailListForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/subscribe.html', {'sub_form': subscribe_form})
```

Comment: show the view you use to render the homepage

Comment: it is just a simple view returning posts to home.html

Comment: `def home_page_view(request):
    posts = Post.published.all().order_by('-publish')[:5]

 
    return render(request, 'pages/page/home.html', {'section': 'home',
                                                                                 'posts': posts }
    )`

Comment: Please add that code to the question. That makes it easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render the same form to another page (view), you can just add that form to the context of the view, like you do on the subscribe page. The homepage view would look like:

```
def home_page_view(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subscribe_form = EmailListForm(request.POST)
        if subscribe_form.is_valid():
            subscribe_form = subscribe_form.save()

            return render(request, 'accounts/subscribe_done.html', {'name': subscribe_form.name})

    else:
        context = {
            'section': 'home',
            'posts': Post.published.all().order_by('-publish')[:5],
            'subscribe_form': EmailListForm()
        }
        
    return render(request, 'pages/page/home.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the way to do that would be to either copy the above code to the home view function or extract a method that gets a request and returns the desired form object. Either way, you pass a form object to the home template just as you would on the subscribe page.

Answer (score 0):

Does using the `{% extends 'xyz.html' %}` work? I usually use that to extend html templates.